# To classify a bike and a bicyclist separately or not?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I'm planning to start a project about **classification of objects in traffic**. Currently I am putting together a custom dataset to train a network (YOLOv4 probably). Thinking ahead about labeling the dataset, I'm wondering whether I should **separately label a bicyclist as a human and a bicycle**, or not.

Looking at the COCO dataset, we can see that humans on bicycles or motorcycles are separately labeled as *'Person'*, and the vehicles as *'Bicycle'* or *'Motorcycle'*. Please see the following example: https://cocodataset.org/#explore?id=67208.

To improve the distinction between a bicycle and a motorcycle, I was planning to label the vehicle including the human, for the reason that the pose and the outfit may help with the classification. But since I will also be looking for pedestrians, I'm now afraid that the person on the bicycle **will often be wrongly classified as a pedestrian**.

Does anyone have experience with this or recommendations for me?

**= Edit =**

To avoid that a person walking around in a motorcycle suit would be classified as '*Motorcycle*' instead of '*Pedestrian*', I now label the person on a motorcycle separately. Whether a detection that is classified as a '*Person*' is a pedestrian, bicyclist, or a motorcyclist, will be decided on in post-processing by checking whether another detection for a motorcycle or bicycle is near the detection of the person.